# how to insert image into all pages of a pdf for a c# console application

Tags: c#, pdf

I created a c# console application for inserting image into the PDF, but this code inserts only into the first page of the PDF.
I found some solutions online but most of them are web oriented rather than a console application. Tried them but didn't work. Here is my code:

```
void InsertImageToPdf(string sourceFileName, string imageFileName, string newFileName)
    {
        using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
        using (Stream imageStream = new FileStream(imageFileName, FileMode.Open))
        using (Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);
            PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageStream);

            image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 100);
            image.ScaleAbsolute(222, 222);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);


            pdfStamper.Close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ITextSharp but the code would be the same between a web app and a console app. I don't see anything that appears to create or access specific pages, a quick search turned up a `PdfConcatenate` class that has an `AddPages` method.

Comment: @chaitanyakrishna how about a loop over all pages?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not a ITextSharp, but it's solve you task on 100%

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfCommon.Initialize();
        InsertImage();
    }

    static private void InsertImage()
    {
        //Load bitmap from file and insert it into page
        using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(@"d:\0\img1.png") as Bitmap)
        {
            using (var doc = PdfDocument.Load(@"d:\0\test_big.pdf"))
            {
                foreach (var page in doc.Pages)
                {
                    var image = InsertImageToPage(doc, page, bmp, new PointF(0, 0));
                    //Insert image into page dictionary
                    InsertIntoDictionary(doc, page, image);
                }
                //Save document
                doc.Save(@"d:\0\6\modified_facture.pdf", SaveFlags.NoIncremental);
            }
        }
    }

    static public PdfImageObject InsertImageToPage(PdfDocument doc, PdfPage page, System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, PointF atPoint)
    {
        var bi = bmp.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        //Create PdfBitmap object from .Net bitmap
        var bitmap = new PdfBitmap(
            bmp.Width,
            bmp.Height,
            BitmapFormats.FXDIB_Argb,
            bi.Scan0,
            bi.Stride);

        //Create pdf image object and then set PdfBitmap object into it.
        var image = PdfImageObject.Create(doc);
        image.SetBitmap(bitmap);

        //Scale image object to it's actual width and heihgt
        image.SetMatrix(bmp.Width, 0, 0, bmp.Height, (float)atPoint.X, (float)atPoint.Y);

        page.PageObjects.InsertObject(image);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bi);
        return image;
    }

    static private void InsertIntoDictionary(PdfDocument doc, PdfPage page, PdfImageObject image)
    {
        //Get page dictionary, list of indirect objects and original page content
        var pageDict = page.Dictionary;
        var list = PdfIndirectList.FromPdfDocument(doc);

        //Convert contents to array. 
        PdfTypeArray array = ConvertContentsToArray(pageDict["Contents"], list, pageDict);

        //Get stream of image.
        IntPtr streamHandle = Pdfium.FPDFImageObj_GenerateStream(image.Handle, page.Handle);
        var stream = PdfTypeStream.Create(streamHandle);

        //Add image's stream into list of indirect objects and then add it to array.
        int num = list.Add(stream);
        array.AddIndirect(list, num);
    }

    static private PdfTypeArray ConvertContentsToArray(PdfTypeBase contents, PdfIndirectList list, PdfTypeDictionary pageDict)
    {
        //check the original content whether it's an array
        if (contents is PdfTypeArray)
            return contents as PdfTypeArray;  //if contents is a array just return it
        else if (contents is PdfTypeIndirect)
        {
            if ((contents as PdfTypeIndirect).Direct is PdfTypeArray)
                return (contents as PdfTypeIndirect).Direct as PdfTypeArray; //if contents is a reference to array then return that array
            else if ((contents as PdfTypeIndirect).Direct is PdfTypeStream)
            {
                //if contents is a reference to a stream then create a new array and insert stream as a first element of array
                var array = PdfTypeArray.Create();
                array.AddIndirect(list, (contents as PdfTypeIndirect).Direct);
                //Add array into list of indirect objects
                list.Add(array);
                //And set it as a contents of the page
                pageDict.SetIndirectAt("Contents", list, array);
                return array;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Unexcpected content type");
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Unexcpected content type");
    }
}
```

Yu can install appropriate package via nuget:
install-package pdfium.net.sdk